# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the foreign key - SQL Server and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have tables called `tbScore`, `tbScoreDetail` and `tbReview`. I have a foreign key column `reviewId` (nullable) in `tbScoreDetail`. It will allow me to insert the row, but while updating the table, it is throwing an exception

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with foreign key constraint "FK_Review_ScoreDetail"

This is my code:

```
public class ScoreDetail
{
    public int ScoreDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ScoreId { get; set; }
    public int? ReviewId { get; set; }
}

public class ReviewId
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public string Review { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code doing the `UPDATE`, and show us some sample data you're working with!

Comment: Are you updating column `reviewId`?  if so, then that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to your mapping settings in the EntityFramework, why do I say this is where the foreign keys are configured and whether or not they are nullable is commanded or by:

```
public int? IndexNullable { get; set ;}
```

Or in the configs where you can configure this way
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx

What it takes to check how your keys are configured in your default entity correctly and the index by your own nomenclature see the keys too and the index on your own when migrations perceive a database of your indexes and very likely that a cases, where an index was created without its explicit intention.